# Proving differentiability of a piecewise function of several variables

Tags: real-analysis

I am struggling to prove that $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 
      \frac{s(y) - s(x)}{y-x} & y\neq x\\
      s'(x) & y=x \\
   \end{cases}$$ (where s(x) is a twice differentiable function $s:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$) is differentiable at any point $(x,y)$ where $x=y$. I know how to check that $f(x,y)$ is continuous at such points, but unsure how to prove differentiability using the definition. Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't vandalize your own posts. If you have asked a question on a public platform then let it be known publicly that you have done so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can start by finding the partial derivatives at $(x, x)$.

For $\partial_1f(x, x)$ we have:

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
\frac{f(x+h, x) - f(x, x)}{h} & = \frac{\frac{s(x+h) - s(x)}{h} - s'(x)}{h} \\
 & = \frac{ s(x + h) - s(x) - s'(x)h }{h^2} \\
 & = \frac{s(x)+s'(x)h + \frac{s''(x)h^2}{2} + o(h^2) - s(x) - s'(x)h}{h^2} \\
 & =\frac{s''(x)}{2} + \frac{o(h^2)}{h^2}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

So $\partial_1f(x, x)=\frac{s''(x)}{2}$ and since $f(x, y)=f(y, x)$, we also have $\partial_2f(x, x)=\frac{s''(x)}{2}$.

Now we can verify that $(h, k) \mapsto \nabla f (x, x) \cdot(h, k)$ is f's derivative at $(x, x)$.